# Which version control systems will allow only one user to work on a file at a time?

Tags: version-control

I'd like it so when I check out a file no one else can edit it until I check it back in. Is there a version control system that allows me to do this? I currently use Subversion and I know it has the 'lock' feature but I want it to do that automatically without me having to request it on each file I'm working on.

Comment: Why do you want to do such a thing?  Allowing simultaneous work is one of the best features of version control.  Perforce can lock a whole changelist at once pretty easily: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.091/manuals/cmdref/lock.html

Comment: @ the close vote: I'd say VCS is pretty programming related

Comment: @Carl Agreed.  This is one of the triumphs of modern version control.  Before version control systems started automatically calculating diffs and providing a mechanism to auto-merge or manually resolve conflicts, the "check-out-and-lock" mechanism was the only one available, and it REALLY causes problems in some teams where a bunch of people touch the same files.

Comment: @Carl - And if you are doing something "creative" and can't have anyone else touch the file or the whole build is hosed? There are circumstances where this is wanted and needed.

Comment: @Oded But a system where this is the default behavior?  In my experience, you're talking edge cases, in which case the manual lock mechanism should be sufficient.

Comment: You do realize that there is no difference between the work of "Get lock" on a file in SVN and "Checkout" in e.g. VSS or other SCM?  In other words, if you want to have an exclusive lock you *must* specify at some point that you want that lock.  You can't automate that, the SCM isn't psychic.

Comment: @Oded, you still don't need to lock the whole project.  Locking on a by-file basis is clearly a required feature.

Comment: svn mergine blows. it gives me tons of text that says 'mine', 'theirs'. thats worthless. if it doesnt do it automatically then whats the point of it?

Comment: @Dathan, @Carl Norum - I agree. Never said the whole project should be locked. See my answer.

Comment: I've seen entire projects get held up because someone went on vacation with "locked" files

Comment: @chadley:  You're doing it wrong.  If you're in a team where people are constantly stepping on each other's toes, then you have a communication problem that no software can solve.  A locking VCS may avoid some problems, but it will create a lot more, and will likely cause deadlocks.

Comment: @Oded:  Then you tell people what you're doing.  A VCS is a wonderful and necessary piece of software, but it can't remove the need to communicate with others.

Comment: @David Thornley - I personally would never use exclusive lock on a project. I agree that it's bad practice and shouldn't replace communication.

Comment: thanks for all your responses guys. after hearing your comments ive realized its the guy im working with thats the problem :) no, im kidding. but seriously, i guess im just not using svn right.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in subversion.  I'd recommend that you dont and instead learn how to merge.  Here's some more information:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.advanced.locking.html

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of them.

Source Safe is notorious for not working any other way.

Serena Dimensions can be configured that way.

TFS will allow you to do an exclusive checkout.

Most source control systems will allow you to do this, some are built that way, other have the functionality in case it is needed.

However, if you are working in a team, doing this will only hurt progress. Being able to have many people work on the same file at one time is not only a time saver but is more efficient use of resources and speeds work along. You should only use exclusive lock in special circumstances, where you really can't have anyone else work on the file.

Comment: Source Safe supports both methods as of SourceSafe 2005.

Comment: I originally used source safe as version control so thats where i got the idea from. I liked it better that way knowing i wouldnt have to worry about my code getting overwritten or lost in merging somewhere. After reading the comments in here though, it seems that it works best for everyone to not lock the files. Generally, id be working in a small team of 3 or so, so I think the locking wouldnt hold us back that much.

Comment: @chadley:  I've been in small teams where locking was a problem.  I suspect it depends more on the nature of the work; new development is probably more separable by locking than urgent bug fixes.  And, yes, merging VCSs can be scary at first and take some getting used to.  Just try one sometime if you can, and see how you like it after you've used it for a month or so.  That's what convinced me.

Answer (score 2):

- CVS
- Clearcase

--

Typically modern VCSs seem to deprecate the lock model of development, preferring a merge model.

edit: SVN merging is - in my opinion - broken. Once you've used ClearCase/Mercurial/git merging... you'll learn that fast. :)

Comment: CVS operates in a merging role by default.  You can put advisory locks in effect if you like, and it is possible to use the older RCS functionality to lock a file, but I don't even remember if that's available except as an admin tool.

Comment: @David: Agreed. But CVS *does* have lock functionality of a sort(reserved checkouts), which is why I added it. `cvs admin -l` I gather.

Answer (score 1):

The old IBM "CMVC" tool works that way, I think. It makes me feel uncomfortable and vaguely sad to think about that however.

Answer (score 0):

Peforce does something close.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SourceSafe (yuck).

Answer (score 0):

[RCS](http://www.gnu.org/software/rcs/) uses locks as the main approach to managing edits. You check out the file, and if you intend to edit it, you lock it. You can force an override on someone else's lock, but if you do, you clobber their changes. See for example this best-practices [discussion](http://www.athabascau.ca/html/depts/compserv/webunit/HOWTO/rcs.htm) for more info.

Comment: RCS is also one of the oldest VCSs around.  It operates on a per-file basis, and neither easily supports a central repository nor offers DVCS-style merging.

Comment: @David Thornley: I'm not advocating RCS vs a modern VCS, but it does answer the question - if you want locking as a major feature by default, there it is. Others have already pointed out that if you're looking for locking as a key feature, you're probably solving the wrong problem.